# Performance gain by implementing streamlined simplex

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

**NOTE:** I'm reposting here because of a comment on my [original question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66628/performance-gain-by-implementing-streamlined-simplex) in Computer Science StackExchange suggesting that maybe it was too implementation-based for that site.

---

I have to solve linear transportation problems for a research project. Ideally, I should design an application that will recieve the problem data as an input and then show some results. The size of the problems are in the order of N=10.000 sources and N=10.000 destinations. Also, there are 2N=20.000 restrictions of equality, one for each source and one for each destination.

I've been using Python's PuLP with the standard solver(COIN-OR) and with GLPK. As a general rule, the performance of COIN-OR is superior than that of GLPK, but even with COIN-OR the problems are taking too long to be solved. As far I as know, there's a streamlined version of the simplex algorithm for transportation problems, but I ignore the magnitude of the improvement in performance I should expect by using that streamlined version of simplex algorithm.

So, my first question is if those solvers identify the transportation problem structure of the problems I'm dealing with and act accordingly.

If the answer turns out to be no, then my second question is if I can exploit that particular structure of the transportation problems with a free solver that has a Python interface.

Also, will I note some improvement if I implement myself the streamlined version of the simplex algorithm? Or implementations must be too far from naive to really beat a well-established simplex solver like the ones I mentioned before?

Comment: To answer your third question: Yes, most likely you won't be able to write a significantly faster implementation without considerable experience in the area. I would suggest you try to write out your problem in some well defined format and try different solvers, just to see what the perfromance difference might be.

Comment: With 100 million LP variables this is not a small problem. PuLP may also be slow on this (likely slower than a good LP solver). Network simplex methods are a little bit out of fashion because (mostly commercial) LP solvers have become very fast.

Comment: If it is for research, why not try Gurobi or CPLEX? You can call them from PuLP, and they do identify the network structure. You can also ask them to use Network Simplex, although their default settings are pretty good in identifying network structure already.

Comment: @Ioannis How would one ask Gurobi to use the Network Simplex solver? (It does not have one I believe).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen My bad: Gurobi does not have a Network Simplex indeed. Reference [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gurobi/cnVL5nN2brU/REeTs6RCCAAJ).